# Binding multi-dimentional arrays in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm trying to bind an property which I know to be a (multi-dimentional) `NSArray` holding `NSArray` objects which in turn hold instances of `NSObject`. I've bound the method as such:

```
[Export ("options")]
NSObject[][] Options { get; set; }
```

When I build my bindings I get the following errors in the generated class for the above property.

From a generated call to `NSArray.FromNSObjects`:

```
(1) Argument `#1` cannot convert 'Foundation.NSObject[][]' expression to type 'Foundation.NSObject[]'.
(2) Error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `Foundation.NSArray.FromNSObjects(params Foundation.NSObject[])' has some invalid arguments (CS1502)
```

From a generated call to `NSArray.ArrayFromHandle<Foundation.NSObject[]>`:

```
(1) Error CS0311: The type `Foundation.NSObject[]' cannot be used as type parameter `T' in the generic type or method `Foundation.NSArray.ArrayFromHandle<T>(System.IntPtr)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from `Foundation.NSObject[]' to `ObjCRuntime.INativeObject' (CS0311)
```

The errors keep referring to the compilers inability to convert between `Foundation.NSObject[][]` and `Foundation.NSObject[]`. I can't see why this would be a problem, `NSArray` is a subclass of `NSObject`, so why can't it treat the second array dimension as an `NSObject`?

(I know I have alternatives, such as binding the Options as `NSObject[]`, or just simply `NSObject`, but I'd rather be as type safe as possible.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this problem arises because the methods `FromNSObjects` and `ArrayFromHandle` can't handle the conversion of multi-dimentional arrays, but I'm not completely sure.

I managed to work around this problem by removing the binding of `Options` from my bindings file (ApiDefinition.cs) and manually binding the property in a partial class.

I wrote two methods to convert between a multi-dimentional `NSArray` and `NSObject[][]`.

```
    private NSArray NSArraysFromTwoDimentionalArray(NSObject[][] firstDimension) {
        NSMutableArray nsFirstDimension = new NSMutableArray ();

        foreach (NSObject[] secondDimention in firstDimension) {
            NSMutableArray nsSecondDimension = new NSMutableArray ();
            foreach (NSObject nsObj in secondDimention) {
                nsSecondDimension.Add (nsObj);
            }
            nsFirstDimension.Add (nsSecondDimension);
        }

        NSArray toReturn = (NSArray)nsFirstDimension.Copy ();

        nsFirstDimension.Dispose ();

        return toReturn;
    }

    private NSObject[][] TwoDimentionalArrayFromArrayOfNSArrays (NSArray[] nsFirstDimension) {
        NSObject[][] firstDimension = new NSObject[nsFirstDimension.Length][];

        int i = 0;
        foreach (NSArray nsSecondDimension in nsFirstDimension) {
            NSObject[] secondDimension = NSArray.ArrayFromHandle<NSObject> (nsSecondDimension.Handle);

            firstDimension[i] = secondDimension;
            i++;
        }

        return firstDimension;
    }
```

I then used the above conversion methods to implement my bindings.

```
    public virtual NSObject[][] Options {
        [Export ("options")]
        get {

            NSArray[] firstDimension;
            if (IsDirectBinding) {
                firstDimension = NSArray.ArrayFromHandle<NSArray> (ApiDefinition.Messaging.IntPtr_objc_msgSend (this.Handle, Selector.GetHandle ("options")));
            } else {
                firstDimension = NSArray.ArrayFromHandle<NSArray> (ApiDefinition.Messaging.IntPtr_objc_msgSendSuper (this.SuperHandle, Selector.GetHandle ("options")));
            }

            return TwoDimentionalArrayFromArrayOfNSArrays (firstDimension);
        }


        [Export ("setOptions:")]
        set {
            if (value == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException ("value");

            var multiNSArray = NSArraysFromTwoDimentionalArray (value);

            if (IsDirectBinding) {
                ApiDefinition.Messaging.void_objc_msgSend_IntPtr (this.Handle, Selector.GetHandle ("setOptions:"), multiNSArray.Handle);
            } else {
                ApiDefinition.Messaging.void_objc_msgSendSuper_IntPtr (this.SuperHandle, Selector.GetHandle ("setOptions:"), multiNSArray.Handle);
            }
            multiNSArray.Dispose ();

        }

    }
```